# Move button into Div

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I need to move this new button into this DIV that already exists.  This seems to me like it should work but doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Button button5 = new Button();
button5.Text = "Five";
button5.CssClass = "buttonCSS";
button5.Click += new EventHandler(button5_Click);
button5.ID = "button5";
this.Controls.Add(button5);               

string myscript = @"      
    var navFooter = document.getElementById('NavFooter');
    var button5 = document.getElementById('button5');
    navFooter.Controls.Add(button5);
    ";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", myscript, true);
```

I know the two objects are being found.  Any ideas?

(Note: I cannot use jQuery.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Controls.Add()` is C#, not JavaScript. To append an element to another element with JavaScript, use `appendChild()`:

```
navFooter.appendChild(button5);
```

Comment: The ID is not the problem.  I am getting the control.  For example, if I do alert(button5.value); then it returns "Five".  Thanks though.

Comment: @user390480, I saw that you mentioned that you were getting the controls. The first part of my answer is merely a suggestion. The second part of the answer should fix your issue. Did you replace your `Controls.Add()` with `.appendChild(button5)`? `Controls.Add()` is not JavaScript, it's C#. `.appendChild()` is the JS equivalent in this case.

Comment: appendChild! That's it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this through javascript?

If you change the containing `<div>` to a `<asp:Panel>`, then you can add the newly created button straight into this panel. The `<asp:Panel>` is rendered simply as a `<div>` html element, and you can add the CssClass to this to keep the styles the same.

Gives you overall greater control on the server side and you don't need to worry about the javascript. Especially since you are doing server side work anyway.

Comment: I do not have access to that code.  The DIV is already there.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add runat="server" to the div, and add it in the code behind:

```
<div id="dvButtonContainer" runat="server" ... >
```

Another option is to use a Panel, as it outputs a div anyway:

```
<asp:Panel ID="dvButtonContainer" runat="server" ... >
```

And in the code behind:

```
Button button = new Button();
dvButtonContainer.Controls.Add(button);
```

**EDIT**: Since DIV is not accessible, here is a workaround:

```
Button Button1 = new Button();

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", String.Format("document.getElementById(\"div1\").appendChild({0});", Button1.UniqueID), true);
```

Comment: I do not have access to that DIV code. The DIV is already there and I cannot change it.